# Basic numerical Optimization/approximation question

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

can someone help me out with this question? I am at a complete loss...

define these two functions:
\begin{align}
f(x, \delta) &= \cos \left(x + \delta\right) - \cos(x) 
\\[.5em]
g(x, \delta) &= -2\sin\left(x + \left( \frac{\delta}{2}\right)\right) \sin\left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)
\end{align}
How are $f(x,\delta)/\delta$ and $g(x, \delta)/\delta$ good approximations of $-\sin(x)$ as $\delta$ becomes smaller and smaller?

Secondly, how can we prove, analytically, that $f = g$ using trig identities only?

Would highly appreciate any insight into this question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use two kind of trigonometric identities. First one is 
$$ \cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b) -\sin(a)\sin(b)$$ 
and the second is 
$$\cos(a) - \cos(b)= -2\sin\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$

The first one is able to prove that $f(x,\delta)$ tends to $\sin(x)$ when $\delta$ tends to $0$ by using the small angles approach:
$\sin(\delta)\approx\delta$ and $\cos(\delta)\approx1$

$$f(x,\delta)=\cos(x+\delta)-\cos(x)=\cos(x)\cos(\delta) -\sin(x) \sin(\delta)-\cos(x) \approx -\delta \sin(x)$$

The second one is able to prove that $f$ and $g$ are equivalent by this replacement: $a=x+\delta$ and $b=\delta$
\begin{align}
f(x,\delta)=\cos(x+\delta)-\cos(\delta)
&=-2\sin\left(\frac{x+\delta+x}{\delta}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x+\delta-x}{2}\right)
\\
&=-2\sin\left(x+\frac{\delta}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\delta}{2}\right)
=g(x,\delta)
\end{align}